# upload and view image in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, image, jsp, spring-mvc

i'm trying to upload an image in the database and then show it on a jsp, in a web application developed with spring MVC.
I've read all the questions concerning to this problem but i didn't get it.
I was thinking about saving the image in a blob field, instead of a clob one. Is it a good idea?

I've created a multipart form with a file input.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="monorigineEdit" modelAttribute="formMonorigineEdit"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
...
    <input type="file" name="image">
...
</form:form>
```

In the controller i get correctly the Multipartfile in this way

```
public String monorigineEdit(@RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "formMonorigineEdit") @Valid MonorigineDTO monorigineDTO, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws FacadeException
```

I would like, for testing purpose, just to forward the image to a jsp in base64 and show it, in this way in the controller

```
...
File auxFile = multipartToFile(file);
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(auxFile);
byte[] byteArrayImage = Base64.encodeBase64(IOUtils.toByteArray(fi));
model.put("myImage", byteArrayImage);
return new String("monorigineEditTemplate");
```

and with this tag in the jsp

```
<img id="myImg" name="myImg" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<c:out value='${myImage}'/>" >
```

The method multipartToFile is this one:

```
public File multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{
    File convFile = new File(multipart.getOriginalFilename());
    multipart.transferTo(convFile);
    return convFile;
}
```

The problem is that the browser doesn't show the image, but i can't get where i'm wrong.

Can you help me? :)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: change jpeg to png in your data:image/jpeg line...Also, you cannot display byte array image, you have to convert it to String.

Comment: It doesn't work and i'm uploading a jpeg file.

Comment: What doesn't work...It's okay to upload a jpeg too....just make it as a png, and you CANNOT display bytearray, you have to convert it to string, refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you convert image to String and display it :

```
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public String convertByteArrayImagetoString(){
            BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

    File imagePath = new File(defaultPersonImagePath);
                    try {
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imagePath);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
                        photoString = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Encoder.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return "";
                    }
}
```

if you have doubts, let me know.